# Changing all "+" to "-" and viceversa with regex JAVA

Tags: java, regex

The button in question should change all the plus sign in minus and viceversa, but i can't find "+" with regex:

```
else if(e.getActionCommand().equals("+/-")) {
        String[] plusminus = text1.split("[\\d.]");

        for(int p = 0; p < plusminus.length; p++) {
            System.out.print(plusminus[p] == "[\\+]"); //This result false with a string like "3+5+4"
            if(plusminus[p] == "\\+") {
                plusminus[p] = "-";
            }
            else if(plusminus[p] == "\\-") {
                plusminus[p] = "+";

            }
        }
        String text3 = "";
        for(String r : plusminus) {
            text3 += r;
        }
        System.out.println(text3);
          text2 = text3;
          this.app.text.setText(text3);
    }
```

What should i do to make signs invert?

Comment: You're using `==` to compare a string to a regex (you can't even compare strings to other strings with `==`, let alone match them to a regex). What do you expect to happen?

Comment: Oh thank you... I changed it using .matches method and now it works

Comment: You don't need to escape the "+" and "-" the way you are using it: `if(plusminus[p].equals("+")) { ... } else if(plusminus[p].equals("-")) { ... }` or you can in fact use regex if you utilize the **String#matches()** method: `if (plusminus[p].matches("[+]")) { ... }`.

Comment: And can't you just use `string.replace()` or `string.replaceAll` instead?

Comment: ``s.replace("+", "-");``

Answer (score 0):

It's common to use [`find`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#find()), [`group`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#group()), [`appendReplacement`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#appendReplacement(java.lang.StringBuilder,java.lang.String)) and [`appendTail`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#appendTail(java.lang.StringBuilder)) of `Matcher`:

```
private static Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[+-]");

public static String flipPlusAndMinus(String text) {
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(text);
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(text.length());
    while (matcher.find()) {
        String group = matcher.group();
        String replacement;
        switch (group) {
            case "+":
                replacement = "-";
                break;
            case "-":
                replacement = "+";
                break;
            default:
                replacement = group;
        }
        matcher.appendReplacement(sb, replacement);
    }
    matcher.appendTail(sb);
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Comment: Code requires Java 9. If you require Java 9 anyway, why go through all that, instead of just doing `return pattern.matcher(text).replaceAll(mr -> mr.group().equals("+") ? "-" : "+");` in one line of code?

Comment: @Andreas Shorter doesn't always mean better. I've been absent from Java for a few years, so I didn't know about the new `replaceAll`. But you're right that this is more idiomatic for Java 9 and beyond. For versions below that, one could replace `StringBuilder` with `StringBuffer` and use my method.

Answer (score 0):

For best performance and least use of space, convert the string to a `char[]` and modify that.

```java
public static String flipPlusAndMinus(String text) {
    char[] buf = text.toCharArray();
    for (int i = 0; i < buf.length; i++) {
        switch (buf[i]) {
            case '+': buf[i] = '-'; break;
            case '-': buf[i] = '+'; break;
        }
    }
    return new String(buf);
}
```